# Objective-C How to list all available carrier network?

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, telephony, carrier

is there a solution for search all operators network telephony available on ios device from objective c or swift ? like it is done in Settings => General => Carrier => set Automatic to false

Carrier Search IOS:

[image: Carrier Search IOS]

Thanks :)

Comment: Not from the public SDK, there maybe a possibility on a jail broken device.  with private API. But I'm not aware of them.

Answer (score 0):

No, you cannot do that in a device. Only in jailbroken device.

Apple is very protective of that kind of thing - an app can't manually assign either a cellular or wireless network for the device to connect to. There is a special chip in the device that handles cellular connections, and only the user can control WiFi connections.